# Adaptable sidenotes?

Tags: margins

I was wondering whether or not it was possible, with any package, to create sidenotes that adapt to the margin. It would look kind of like this: [image]

Comment: with some manual control around page breaking, you could set that with `wrapfig`

Comment: The `memoir` class provides a variety of sidenotes but not like what you are after. It seems that you want the first side note to change the page layout by decreasing the `\textwidth` and increasing the margin, put any other sidenotes in the expanded margin and after the last sidenote on the page revert the page layout to its original state. I have no idea about how to do this autimatically via LaTeX code.

Comment: Even paracol and flowfram can't handle paragraphs which span different widths.  You can use \nopar and \splitpar (custom) to handle the change.

Comment: For an extensive use of sidenotes, although it will not allow changes of  width in the middle of the paragraph,  my  suggestion is the tufte clasess: See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353560/11604) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99695/11604).