# Floats in text with indents

Tags: floats, indentation

In an effort to make this as concise and clear as I possibly can, I will format this in the form of lists.

### 1. What I aim to achieve

- Being able to properly place **floats** within a text with **shifted left margin**. The desired output is depicted below. Please do not mind the Korean.
- **Minipage is not an option**, for the **text may need to break across pages**.
- A **general** solution *(i.e. **not specific** to particular texts and images, save for extreme edge cases)*

### 2. Answers I **do not** aim to receive

- *"Prudent"* answers that tell me to **avoid floats**. I have to use them. *(Because aesthetics is important in a textbook)* If there are any other options that suggest the use of an element functionally identical to floats, that is fine.
- Solutions that use **unbreakable environments**.

### 3. What I did try

- Using **adjustbox** or **enumerate**. Failed because **wrapfigure does not work in them**.

### 4. Desired Output

Please do not mind the Korean.
[image: Desired Output]

Comment: You can use paracol to achieve the desired look, but you have to manually break the paragraph.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620345/indentation-problem-with-wrapfigure-and-listings/620404?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C35.7877#620404 for example.

Comment: A float is an unbreakable environment by nature, so  what you really ask is impossible.  You may be interested in tufte classes to place figures of text at margin or extent main text in that margin, tht couls mimic a  wrapfig  (see examples [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491290/11604) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353560/11604)), but only the main text is breakable, never the associated side floats.